# How to auto refresh a window in gtk3 c

Tags: c, gtk3

I use a robot to make a choice in the game;
When I make my choice I can with a g_signal_connect make a G_CALLBACK and execute gtk_main_quit() to continue and then refresh the page, but the problem is when the robot must make his choice my program can't continue manually after gtk_main() and the robot can't make her choice.
any way to refresh the page durring execution without make a click ?

Comment: you can execute another function, not `gtk_main_quit`. Like `robots_turn`.

Comment: @AlexanderDmitriev the problem is not what I must execute but how ,because the code is stoped by gtk_main() and if I want to execute something I must make a manual action like a click to execute the function this is nice in my turn and I did it ,But in robot turn there is no way to execute it automatically ,what I want is to keep robot woking even if the window is displayed .

Comment: Then don't stop it with `gtk_main_quit`.